# Android - Inflate view, runnable or animations drain battery?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

I am building a game where i do some things in simple steps...

- In Handler Object I set post delayed runnable(new instance of runnable)
- In the runnable I call method where I inflate random layout from layout id list. My layout has ImageView.
- I add inflated ImageView layout in the desiret view parrent.
- I am creating fadein animation object to the ImageView layout I just added and start it.
- After on fadein animation end I creae new animation object where i move the ImageView layout by changing it's margins. For this I use `applyTransformation`
- On end of moving animation I remove the view from the ViewGroup and start from the beginning.... This means I add new runnable object to the handler....

This cost me too much battery drain.....

For the durations of the runnable and the animations I use random values in range I specify so in most efficient scenario i have not more than 20 views moving on screen.

Playing the game for 5 mins drain my battery 5% or more.

My main question is: **Which of my actions drain my battery?**

I don't know if it's the inflating or the animations or the runnables...

My second question is: **How to slove the problem?**

If it's the animations... is is better to have just one(of a kind.. i have 2 kinds of animations) animation object just reinitialize it or ?

I know it's better to use OpenGL but I think it will be hard for me to learn it just for this basic functions. I don't know but i think this basic functions are hard to do there. If they are not I will do it with OpenGL

If it's something else just please tell me where is the drain battery problem...

**I am sure that it's draining battery because it's on top of battery usage native Android app it's like 30%**

Comment: I'm guessing your biggest battery drain is keeping the screen on for 5 minutes, not necessarily anything you are doing wrong in your app.

Comment: in battery usage it's on top...